# Developing a backend server in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, rabbitmq, akka

I'm looking into possible ways to go about developing a backend server with these tasks:

- processing messages that arrive via RabbitMQ (the processing basically goes something like this: load some domain model entity using Hibernate and let it do it's stuff)
- should be pluggable. For different customers different modules will be loaded. Each customer is a separate instance.
- some of these modules will probably have to expose services of different kinds (REST, maybe SOAP, ...)
- should enable me to remove most of the boiler plate code (like transaction management, logging), either via AOP or some other mechanism.

For some background. I did such things in .NET using a windows service, Castle Windsor, NHibernate and NServiceBus or some other messaging solution. So I could say I'm biased against a single monolithic solution (that's the imperssion I am getting of Java EE and similar) and woudl rather use a few smaller frameworks or libraries to achieve all this. As long as they run in the same application server.

The options I'm currently looking into are:

- A Java EE application server like GlassFish which is supposed to be able to do all these things (JPA, Hibernate, ...)
- [Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/) and Akka actors connected to RabbitMQ, where Akka actors process the messages and invoke domain model methods. There will be a separate application for the web UI developed in Play.
- [Netty](https://netty.io/)
- Spring as an alternative to Java EE in a Jetty container

I am just starting out in the Java ecosystem so I could use a few general pointers and clarifications if I got some things confused...

**Edit:**

Adding other options:

- OSGi
- [Axon](http://www.axonframework.org/)

Answer (score 2):

For this I would suggest using OSGi in an application server like you mentioned.

You can then use the web container for thigns like REST and SOAP services and an OSGi bundle for running processes that can tackle the MQ messages.

If you want to have the boiler plate stuff managed use Spring, it has great AOP, transaction management and it also integrates well with MQ and Hibernate.

Use Spring integration in the OSGi bundles for the MQ stuff.

For an application server you could try using Spring DM Server. 
http://www.springsource.org/dmserver

This should give you a lot of flexibility although I confess I havent used it myself

Comment: Which aplication server server did you have in mind?

Comment: @jl updated my answer to include this

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Camel Integration Framework](http://camel.apache.org/). It allows you to define pipelines (or endpoints, the Camel term for it), and define rules how and where different messages are distributed. 
Just for example, it can take an HTTP message, transform it, and pass it onwards, possible by other media types (such as a queue or mail), and all with minimal coding.
It has a Java, Scala and Spring DSL, and can run as a standalone, web, or OSGi application.
I highly recommend it from my experience.

Comment: Akka has also nice camel support, you can look into that, too.